# Java generics - Class<?> constructor argument issue

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, search, hibernate-search

I've used Java for quite some time now, but some things are still not very clear to me, especially when it comes to generics...

Here's the thing: I have this `Search` class that I'm using ([see here for details](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/wiki/Search)), that is constructed like this:

```
public Search(Class<?> searchClass) {...}
```

Further more, I have a parametrized generic wrapper around this, as follows:

```
public class HibernateSearch<E> extends Search implements Serializable {
    public HibernateSearch(Class<E> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }
    // ... omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, what I need is the following: I'd like to create parametrized class, that contains this class as its field, e.g.

```
public class BaseSelectorComposer<T> extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

    private HibernateSearch<T> searchObject;
    ...
    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        this.searchObject =
             new HibernateSearchObject<T>( now what...??? );
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I think that the problem I'm facing is obvious from the given example.
Can someone advise what can be done here, or some alternative ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass the responsibility on to whoever actually instanciates and uses instances of `BaseSelectorComposer`, i.e.:

```
public class BaseSelectorComposer<T> extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

    private HibernateSearch<T> searchObject;
    private final Class<T> theType;

    public BaseSelectorComposer(Class<T> token) {
        theType = token;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        this.searchObject = new HibernateSearchObject<T>(theType);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If your `BaseSelectorComposer` is an abstract subclass, which is only ever used like

```
class IntSelectorComposer extends BaseSelectorComposer<Integer> {
    ...
}
```

i.e., as base class for classes, which "bind" the type parameters, there are ways to [obtain the type information via reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) (though this is incredibly ugly, since this is not really well-supported in the API IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a hard-to-workaround scenario. Coming from .NET background, I have personally found very few cases where I could work this out, since Java does not support static generic type resolution (like for instance in .NET where you can use `typeof(T)`).

To work this around I recommend that you find a way to either get the class externally, or an instance of that class. A possible solution would be to change the `doAfterCompose` method in one of the following ways:

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Window comp, Class<?> entityClass) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    this.searchObject =
         new HibernateSearchObject<T>(entityClass);
    ...
}
```

-or-

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Window comp, SomeEntity entity) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    this.searchObject =
         new HibernateSearchObject<T>(entity.getClass());
    ...
}
```

If you cannot modify the method signature (I see it is an override), try to use a member of the class `BaseSelectorComposer<T>` that will hold the desired `Class<?>` instance.

```
public class BaseSelectorComposer<T> extends SelectorComposer<Window> {
    private Class<?> entityClass;

    public BaseSelectorComposer<T>(Class<?> entityClasss) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

   ....
    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        this.searchObject =
            new HibernateSearchObject<T>(this.entityClass);
       ...
    }
}
```